# What is coef_ in Lasso Regression in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What does `coef_` store?

`coef_` originates from the Lasso regression method when trying to accomplish feature selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores the [parameter vector](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html), describing the weights you multiply each feature by to get your predicted values. Essentially, `coef_` are the parameters of your model (excluding the regularisation and the intercept (w0) term - see below).

When using Lasso regression you are performing linear regression with regularisation. 
Without regularisation your predicted value for a given instance is of the form:

> y = w0 + w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + … + wn * xn

where  y is your predicted value and your parameter vector is **w** = [w0, w1, w2, ..., wn] and your feature vector for the training instance is **x** = [x1, x2, ..., xn]. When you are performing your regression you are changing the values of the parameter vector (or 'weight vector') to get the predicted values which minimize the differences between the predicted values and the target values. This is achieved by minimizing a cost function (a measure of how far your predictions vary from the true values).

With (lasso) regularisation use simply add the l1 norm of the parameter vector to the cost function (which you minimize) which helps keep the values of the feature vector as small as possible.